# How to use NSArray in objective C. Card Deck on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I´m all new to Objective C and I can´t seem to find how to do this (if it´s even possible).

I have a `NSArray` filled with 4 Cards (Card = my own Class) and I want to set the text of a label to a `NSString` which my card objects holds.

In Java I would do something like this:
If I have an Card Array with 4 Cards and theLabel is a String.

```
theLabel = deck[2].getLabel();
```

This don´t seem to work on Objective C. My code in Objective C so far:

```
- (IBAction)nextCard:(id)sender {
    theLabel.text = [deck objectAtIndex:j].getLabel;
    theImage.image = [deck objectAtIndex:j].getImage;
}
```

nextCard calls every time I click on a button on the iPhone. 
j is an ordinary int that will keep track on which card to show.

It looks like this when I am creating the array:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ah = [[Card alloc]init];
    [ah setLabel:@"label1"];
    [ah setCardImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png" ]];

    as = [[Card alloc]init];
    [as setLabel:@"label2"];
    [as setCardImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png" ]];

    ac = [[Card alloc]init];
    [ac setLabel:@"labbel3"];
    [ac setCardImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png" ]];

    ad = [[Card alloc]init];
    [ad setLabel:@"label4"];
    [ad setCardImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png" ]];

    deck = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];
    [deck addObject:ah];
    [deck addObject:as];
    [deck addObject:ac];
    [deck addObject:ad];
}
```

So I would basically want to be able to use methods ob objects stores in a NSArray.

Would really appreciate answers, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could perhaps show us your card class? At least the header? The current code suggests that you might be trying to set a UILabel to an NSString...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In objective-C the generated getter hasn't the get prefix, so you use it that way:

```
theLabel = deck[2].label;
```

Or:

```
theLabel= [deck[2] label];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
[deck objectAtIndex:0].label;
```

or:

```
[[deck objectAtIndex:0] label];
```

or:

```
[[deck objectAtIndex:0] yourMethodWithParameter:@"foo"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, in most cases the accessor methods are auto generated.
Let us say we have a property named "object"
The getter method is not named like this `getObject` , where "object" is the property you want to access.
It is named simply by the name of the property like this `object`

So in your case it should be something like this:

```
NSString *theLabelString = [[deck objectAtIndex:j] label];
//or this:
NSString *theLabelString = [deck[j] label];
//or this:
NSString *theLabelString = deck[j].label;
```